# Program closes abruptly at if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the part of my code that doesn't work. The `else` statement works fine but when the `password` is wrong the program just closes abruptly.

```
if logged_in == 'admin':
            tries = -3
            while tries < 0:
                password = input("enter supersecret password. ")
                if password != 'strange alien colour':
                    print("incorrect password. Try again. " + tries + " tries left.")
                    tries = tries + i
                else:
                    print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
                    input()
                    import sys
                    sys.exit(0)
```

This is the entire code:

```
users = ['anonymous', 'me', 'bill', 'me123']
i = 1
while i == 1:
    logged_in = input("Username:\n")

    if logged_in == 'admin':
        tries = -3
        while tries < 0:
            password = input("enter supersecret password. ")
            if password != 'strange alien colour':
                print("incorrect password. Try again. " + tries + " tries left.")
                tries = tries + i
            else:
                print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
                input()
                import sys
                sys.exit(0)

    if logged_in in users:
        print ("Hello " + logged_in + ", welcome back!")
        break

    else:
        print ("invalid username. Do you wish to create an account? (Y/N)\n")
        create_account = input()
        if create_account == 'Y' or create_account == 'y':
            new_username = input("Enter new username: ")
            print("You have creted a new account. Welcome, " + new_username)
            users.append(new_username)
        else:
            print ("Goodbye.")
            break
input()
```

Comment: Please show an example run of your program, including user input and any resulting errors.

Comment: I guess there's some output when your program "closes abruptly"? An error message telling you *why* it closed. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Probably *`TypeError: must be str, not int`*?

Comment: No, there was no error, the program compiled normally but when I ran it it just closed whenever I reached the `if` part.

Comment: What does that mean, "closed"? If you're running this in some environment that pops up a new window and immediately closes that window when the program ends, thus hiding any output… find a different way to run your program.

Comment: That's exactly what happens. I was using SublimeText to compile it, and it showed no errors. I ran it by just opening the .py file. Now I'm using PyCharm and it shows me the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is that on this line

```
print("incorrect password. Try again. " + tries + " tries left.")
```

`tries` is an int, whereas the other parts are strings. As you cannot add these two types, you get an error which is

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

To fix this just change the line to

```
print("incorrect password. Try again. " + str(tries) + " tries left.")
```

On an unrelated note, it is usually recommended that imports are at the top of your program.

Comment: Why didn't I see this error? I am using SublimeText and it compiled just fine. 
Thank you for the help, it works now.

Comment: @AdamGrey Python codes are interpreted. So you don't see errors before execution. You should use an IDE (such as PyCharm) to get warnings about Syntax errors. PyCharm IDE has got a very good Intellisense functionality.

Comment: I thought Sublime Text was an IDE. Thanks for the advice, am downloading PyCharm.

Comment: Sublime Text is a text editor. PyCharm is one of the best IDE for Python!

Answer (score 1):

```
print("incorrect password. Try again. " + tries + " tries left.")
```

This is incorrect as tries is an integer and therefore cannot be concatenated with the two other parts in the quotation marks as they are strings and needs to be converted into a string first to do so. eg.

```
print("incorrect password. Try again. " + str(tries) + " tries left.")
```